# How to add the row of pattern problem to a list in python

Tags: python, list, design-patterns, append

```
a="5234"
for k in range(len(a)):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a)-i):
            print(a[j],end=" ")        
        print()
    a=a[1:]
```

And I got the output as:

```
5 2 3 4  
5 2 3   
5 2   
5   
2 3 4   
2 3   
2   
3 4   
3   
4
```

Now I want to add each row in the above output appended to a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a="5234"
l = []
for k in range(len(a)):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        l.append(a[:len(a)-i])
    a=a[1:]
print(l)
```

Result:

```
['5234', '523', '52', '5', '234', '23', '2', '34', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to you have used nested `for` loop,I recommend you append these elements in last loop.

```
a="5234"
l = []
for k in range(len(a)):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        l.append(a[:len(a)-i])
    a=a[1:]
print(l)
```

Result:

```
['5234', '523', '52', '5', '234', '23', '2', '34', '3', '4']
```

Comment: @VarunKumar If answer helped, consider accept it by checking the mark besides the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

the `for` loop is used to append the output into a list

```
row_out=list()
for k in range(len(a)):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        temp = list()
        for j in range(len(a)-i):
            print(a[j],end=" ")
            temp.append(a[j])
        print()
        row_out.append(temp)
    a=a[1:]

print(row_out)
```